# The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint when foreign key value is untouched

Tags: c#, sql

I am using SQL through C# to make an update to a row in a table as shown below

```cs
context.AssessmentInvitation.Attach(assessmentInvitation);
context.Entry(assessmentInvitation).State = EntityState.Modified;
await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

When this is executed in some cases, I get an exception on `SaveChangesAsync` due to a foreign key constraint. The foreign key constraint has to do with a `CompanyId` as part of the `assessmentInvitation` object being updated. This constraint is set to cascade on update, which seems to be the common solution to this issue. This did not resolve the issue for me.

The interesting thing is that the update causing this issue is not touching this foreign key at all. It is only updating a BIT to set it to true. No other values are being modified. The BIT is not related to any other table in any way, it is not part of any type of key.

Why would this foreign key constraint be relevant to the update at all if it is remaining the same? How can I fix this issue?

edit: The problem was much more simple than I thought. It was using a stored procedure that was not fetching the entire AssessmentInvitation object. Actually, it excluded the CompanyId completely. So when I tried to update without the existing CompanyId, obviously it failed. I thought I was going to learn something about Entity Framework, instead I realized I'm not very good at going through other people's code.

Comment: Does `AssessmentInvitation` have a navigation property to the `Company` entity? Can you show the full class for  `AssessmentInvitation` definition please.

Comment: Is ID a string or number?  I suspect the database has null and it is a number.

Comment: The Id is an Int and it is never null in any case where I am seeing this issue. I am not creating an instance from scratch, I am fetching an AssessmentInvitation, setting a BIT value to true, then calling this update

Comment: It is worth noting that this functionality does work in most cases, but fails in some cases for some reason unknown to me

Comment: The only way that `on update cascade` applies is when you're modifying the *primary key*... it cascades to all child tables so as not to break the referential integrity of existing records. I'm guessing that `companyId` is not the primary key of `AssessmentInvitation` so that wouldn't be relevant here.

Comment: CompanyId is a foreign key referencing the Company table. I referenced on update cascade, not on delete. There is no deletion happening.

Comment: Sorry, meant to say `on update cascade` (original comment corrected)...  You can remove the bit about updating on cascade because it doesn't apply to this situation. That should help you narrow your focus, too.

Comment: If you want help can you please post the full definition of `AssessmentInvitation` including navigation properties!

Comment: I added the AssessmentInvitation definition and some proposed changes. I have not made the changes yet because this is in production currently, but would these changes fix the issue?

Comment: don't tell me you don't have a development/testing environment where you can try out before pushing to production...

Answer (score 0):

I can't add a comment so I'm posting an answer hope it helps you,

try to inspect the properties of `assessmentInvitation` to see if it holds a correct `companyId` value, if you are creating the object or created by the model binder in request it may has it's `CompanyId` set to null.